How can we catch error 429(Too many requests) in .net framework 4.7.2?
HttpStatusCode in .net framwork 4.7.2 does have the 429 error code.
what else can we use instead of this to catch the 429 error specifically because i want to perform some operation only when there is 429 error issue.
 catch (WebException ex)
 {
     if (ex.Response is HttpWebResponse response && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.)
     {

     }
 }

this is the current catch block i am using but  HttpStatusCode doesnt contain any property for 429.

While there is no predefined enum value for the HTTP status code 429 you can still cast the integer 429 into HttpStatusCode:
response.StatusCode == ((HttpStatusCode)429)

